# How Do I Easily Populate Entity Framework Context Initializer With Test Data?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first, objectcontext

Is there any way to generate a context initializer from database entries etc?

I am using Code First 4.2 and want to have a consistent set of data to start my application.

I have a large context I want to populate and I don't want to manually type it out. Also is there anyway to generate random data etc that meets the requirements of the entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could use are the DataGeneration plans that the DatabaseProject has. We use them to generate our test data with some meaningful values.

[Here you can find a walktrough.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833267.aspx)

Or you could use Sql Server Management Studio to script the data that is currently in your database and execute that script in your Initializer.

Comment: Yeah both good ideas. I was hoping to get the actual objects into Initializer so that people could see them etc.

Comment: With actual objects you mean you want a var x = new <Type>() { all properties set } in your code generated from the database?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to increase visibility of what the program is doing to developers. I know sticking stuff in the DB with SQL is fine. However a lot of our systems have been hiding code/functionality in the DB (that din't have to be there) and I have been trying to move us towards keeping functionality in the code.

Comment: I could imagine using a Builder Pattern, the Entity Framework mapping and a T4 template to script a database to code... But I think that would be really hard to write.. Maybe a nice challenge for a rainy afternoon ;)

Comment: Lol yeah. If you see some of my other questions on T4 you may realise it would be more like a rainy week! Thanks for help